# sort_link routing error for ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I've been using sort_link to sort the links on my page

```
= sort_link(@search, :project_token, "Project ID")
```

it works fine......but when the user filters something it takes me to the url discounts/set_filter and once it goes there the sortable links do not work anymore and throws a routing error

```
  No route matches [GET] "/manager/reports/discounts/set_filter"
```

I've went over the documentation and viewed the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast on it......Ryan Bates does address the issue but he fixes it by moving it to the filter.html.haml partial which is not what I want.....i want to keep my links sortable like that without getting this error

any suggestions?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

so i solved this problem by adding a {action: 'show'} to each one of my sort_link

```
  %th.align_left 
    = sort_link(@search, :project_token, "Project ID", { action: "show" })
  %th.align_center 
    = sort_link(@search, :project_district_name, "District", { action: "show" })
  %th.align_center 
    = sort_link(@search, :property_city, "Property Address", { action: "show" })
  %th.align_center 
    = sort_link(@search, :created_at, "Application Date", { action: "show" })
  %th.align_center 
    = sort_link(@search, :submitter_first_name, "Submitted By", { action: "show" })
  %th.align_center 
    = sort_link(@search, :discount_code, "Code", { action: "show" })
```

This works but I'm still not sure if this is the best approach...seems like im violating the D.R.Y principle here.

any suggestions would be helpful

Thanks!